# Fixed position nav bar replacement

Tags: html, css, css-position

I try to use the

```
position:fixed;
width:10in;
```

but when resize the browser, the contents go out of boundary(there's no way to reach those elements).

i need an alternative because i want the nav bar to be at top at all times.

edit: i also want the contents to be inline which is **not** served by using

```
width:100%;
display:inline or inline-block
```

check here - http://jsfiddle.net/dF4Bx/1/

In simple language -

I need that the browser should provide a horizontal bar if the width is not fullfilled by the resized window.

Comment: `with:10in;` or you meant to write `width:10in;`??

Answer (score 1):

Making your top bar sticky with CSS

```
#header{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below CSS,

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:99;
```

`8In` is such a big value and moreover it is **fixed width** that's why it keeps going beyond browser. Use `%` values for responsive designs.

So change width like this

```
div.back div.front {
width:100%;
}
```

then about keeping the elements inline,

Use something like `margin-left:20%` instead of `24In` in `padding:24px 20px 24px 2in!important;`.

Even it will break the line when it reaches a limited browser window. You can reduce this range by avoiding larger fixed values of padding and width in your code.

Check Fiddle: [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmVgz/1/)

Comment: @VaibhavVt pls check the updated fiddle in my answer

Comment: check my edit... ur css doesnt let the code to be inline after resize

Comment: @VaibhavVt Could you serve your HTML here

Comment: i've added images of nav bar both before n after resize

Comment: @VaibhavVt content inline means?? are you talking about avoiding the wrapping of contents to next line while browser width is reduced??

Comment: @VaibhavVt you should make the inner elements also in `%` width to make it adapt with the browser window. Serve your full `nav` html here or setup a **fiddle**. So that i can help you

Comment: still same problem. I need that the browser should provide a horizontal bar if the width is not fullfilled by the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

to arrive to your purpose you can try this code :

```
.divClass{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 80% /*for responsible width*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what's your problem.

Use this HTML instead of yours:

```
<div class="back">
        <div id="header" class="front">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li style="float: right;">Login</li>
                <li style="float: right;">Register</li>
                <li style="float: right;">Search: <input type="text" class="textbox" name="sr"></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And put this rule into your CSS:

```
#header ul li {
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

And too, change this width `8in` to `95%`:

```
div.back div.front {
    background-color: #0072C6 !important;
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Note that i removed the inline style padding of search element.